# Can I check whether a multipolygon contains point in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I got one column (`latlon`) which is a `ST_MultiPolygon`.

The other geometry is a point which I just want to check if it is inside one of my MultiPolygons.

I tried:

```
SELECT ST_CONTAINS(latlon, ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(48.208417 16.372472)')
FROM districts
```

It always returns false; why can't I check if a point is within a multipolygon  with `ST_Contains`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

it worked like this:

```
SELECT name, st_contains(latlon, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(16.391944 48.218056)', 4326))  FROM bezirks
```

Comment: Also, you can use a sub query to specify the B geometry. SELECT name,ST_Contains(latLon,(SELECT geom FROM b WHERE id = 3)) FROM bezirks

Answer (score 3):

The st_contains works with multi geometries.
You must ensure that the point is on the same coordinate system of polygon geometry.

Also you must know that if the point falls into boundary of your multipolygon it will not be considered contained. In this case it will return false since no point inside of polygon geometry.